# How to show one image instead of four images

Tags: php, mysqli, while-loop

In Mysql database I have column name "product_id" and there is while statement code to check if row exist ...

If value of product_id exist, then it will show "note-icon.png" image, if not exit it will say "No" but the problem is that let say that in "product_id" has four product_id's SAME NUMBER and then result will SHOW FOUR images, my question is that how to write code to show ONE image instead of FOUR images!

```
            <?php 
            $sql = new mysqli($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);
            $query = "SELECT * FROM notes WHERE product_id = $product_id";
            $results = mysqli_query($sql, $query);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
           if(isset($row['$product_id'])) {
            echo "<p>No </p>";
            } else {
            echo '<img src="images/note-icon.png" width="16" height="16" />';
            } }
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can use grouping

```
SELECT * FROM notes WHERE product_id = ? GROUP BY product_id
```

Comment: yes is works great, i never thought about using GROUP thanks so much for your help. I mean that thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Select only one row:

**MySQL**:

```
SELECT * FROM notes WHERE product_id = ? LIMIT 1
```

**SQL**:

```
SELECT FIRST 1 * FROM notes WHERE product_id = ?
```

If you want to get all notes but draw one image per product you can do this:

```
$product_ids = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
  if(!isset($row['product_id'])) {
    echo "<p>No </p>";
  } else {
    if(!isset($product_ids[$row['product_id']])) {
      $product_ids[$row['product_id']] = 1;
      echo '<img src="images/note-icon.png" width="16" height="16" />';
    }
  } 
}
```

Some code annotations:
   `$product_id` in your query allowed, only if you are cast it to int before
else use placeholders (prepared statements)

```
if(isset($row['$product_id']))
```

What's this? think should be:

```
if(!isset($row['product_id']))
```

also you forgot to check `$results`, that it is not `false`, before using..

Comment: The limit 1 is not working because is show only one row per records, this case is involved with pagination so I have 30 records in pagination and image i want to show one image in column field if same product_id number has value more then ONE same value number.

Comment: your original query selects all rows with **same** product_id

Comment: read your question again and try to understand what the writer want to get.. I don't know anything about other than product_id fields in your table..

Comment: my question are clear, my question didn't say how to echo limit 1 row, it said "How to write code to make image unlimited same images into ONE image. plain simple.